# AWS DynamoDB using multiple region for better security?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

very often, we heard news about a company got hacked and the user's detail were stolen, but credit card information are safe because they are "stored in a different database (in another region)".

Previously, with an on-site database, like `SQL Server`, I would have designed in such a way that user-related data is stored in a SQL Server location in North America, and any credit card information will be stored in another SQL Server location in Europe.

However, in `DynamoDB`, is such design still needed? E.g. storing user's data in `us-west-1`, and credit card information in `eu-north-1`.

DynamoDB already has such a sophiscated security control and compliances - with IAM and detailed fine-grained access control - is such a multi-region design (in the scope of security) still necessary?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

A multi-region architecture within a single AWS account *will not* appreciably increase security.

There are essentially two ways to gain access to data:

- An exploit within your application that allows untrusted code execution.
- Exposed credentials.

In AWS, credentials are at the level of an account. So if you have `dynamodb:Scan` permission on all tables (`Resource: "*"`) it doesn't matter what region they're in. And if you have Scan permission that's limited to table `Foo`, it doesn't matter whether table `Bar` is in the same region; you can't access it.

Some practices that *do* work:

- Don't expose your application to the Internet. Lock down the security groups to the minimum necessary access, and use a load balancer to limit attack surface on your app-server.
- Run your application in a private subnet so that any exploits won't be able to exfiltrate data.
- Keep your application dependencies up to date! Pay attention to [CERT alerts](https://us-cert.cisa.gov/ncas/alerts) that might affect you.
- Limit IAM privileges, so that an application or user can only access the resources that they need to do their work (no wildcarded resources!).
- Use instance roles rather than long-term credentials. These have an extremely limited lifetime, so even if they are leaked there's little that an attacker can do.

Comment: are you implying that multiple AWS account is a better design (in the scope of security)? I've followed all of the best practices that you've listed and from aws documentation. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/best-practices-security-preventative.html)

Comment: Separate accounts _can_ be a better design, but their primary benefit in my opinion is to prevent the _accidental_ damage that happens when development and production resources are in the same account.

Comment: You can grant cross-account permissions, but in that case you have the same security issues described above. If you grant account A access to all resources in account B, and the credentials used by account A are compromised, then account B has also been compromised.